# copying integers from char array depending on number of bytes in C

Tags: c, memcpy

I have one character array of 8 bytes containing integer values. I need to copy the 1 byte to one integer variable, next 4 bytes to different integer variable, next 3 bytes to another integer variable.
I have used "memcpy" but the results are not proper.

My try:

```
    unsigned char bytes[8];
    int Data1 = 32769;
    int Data2 = 65535;

    int logic1 = 0;
    int logic2 = 0;
    int logic3 = 0;

    memcpy(&bytes[0], &Data1, sizeof(Data1));
    memcpy(&bytes[4], &Data2, sizeof(Data2));

//Value of bytes[] array after this operation is
//bytes[0] = 1
//bytes[1] = 128
//bytes[2] = 0
//bytes[3] = 0
//bytes[4] = 255
//bytes[5] = 255
//bytes[6] = 0
//bytes[7] = 0



    memcpy(&logic1,&bytes,1);
    memcpy(&logic2,&bytes + 1,4);
    memcpy(&logic3,&bytes + 5,1);

My output should be :
logic1 = bytes[0]
logic2 = bytes[1] to bytes[4]
logic3 = bytes[5] to bytes[7]
```

Comment: What results are you getting...

Comment: I am getting logic1 = 1, logic2 = 8, logic 3 = 0.    Sorry, my output should be logic1 = bytes[0]    logic2 = bytes[1] to bytes [4]     logic3 = bytes[5] to bytes[7].

Comment: I am getting output as 1 1 224 see link http://ideone.com/mQ9LV6

Comment: Result should be logic1 = 1, logic2 = 2147483903, logic3 = 255

Comment: logic2 cannot be positive since the MSB will be 1 which means it will be a negative number.

Comment: Yes you are right. But if we will copy 4 bytes i.e. from bytes[1] to bytes[4] then as bytes[1]=128, bytes[2] = 0, bytes[3] = 0, bytes[4] = 255 so, the output should be binary of(128), binary of (0), binary of (0) and binary of(255) combined. Am i right?

Comment: Yes it will be but if the Msb is set it will be negative that is for sure... 255 binary is 11111111. and the number will be 11111111 00000000 00000000 10000000

Comment: Yes exactly my result. So my output should be -2130706560. But it is not coming this also. I am using the code suggested by "user3386109" now. See down for the code.

Comment: No it should be -16777088 ... Take a look at this article for how negative number are stored in memory http://www.programminglogic.com/how-computers-represent-negative-binary-numbers/

Comment: @Avinash Pandey: Yes i got it now. Thanks for the quick response and help. :)

Comment: I tried upvoting but it says upvote requires atleast 15 reputations. As i am new to stack overflow i dont have that much reputation. :(

Comment: You can use   memcpy(&logic1,bytes,1);  memcpy(&logic1,(bytes+1),1);  memcpy(&logic1,(bytes+5),1)..instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you meant

```
memcpy( &logic1, &bytes[0], 1 );
memcpy( &logic2, &bytes[1], 4 );
memcpy( &logic3, &bytes[5], 3 );
```

Note that `&bytes` is a pointer to the **whole** array, so `&bytes + 1` points beyond the end of the array, and `&bytes + 5` is way beyond the end of the array. Hence you get undefined behavior, and unexplainable results.

Comment: Couldn't you also simply do `bytes + 1` rather than `&bytes[1]` since that's just syntactic sugar for `&*(bytes + 1)`?

Comment: By using the above code I am getting correct value for logic1 and logic3 i.e 1 and 255 respectively but for logic2 the value is negative i.e. -16777088 which is not as i expected.

Comment: @kid Yes, `bytes + 1` is the same as `&bytes[1]`. The last syntax in your comment (although technically correct) is an abomination :)

Comment: @sats The most significant byte is the 255, so the number in hex is 0xff000080, which is -16777088 in decimal, so that is the answer that I would expect on a little endian processor.

Comment: @user3386109: yes you are right. The result is correct. Thanks a lot for the help. :)